# How to call this subroutine?

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine, nios

I'm learning MIPS 32 bit assembly in the NIOS II IDE and I've got a complete working subroutine that multiplies two numbers stored in r4 and r5 and return the result in r2:

```
      .global muladd            # makes label "main" globally known

        .text                   # Instructions follow
        .align  2               # Align instructions to 4-byte words

muladd:
   movi r2, 0 # total = 0
   movi r8, 0 # i = 0
L1:   # if( i >= a ) goto L2
   bge r8, r4, L2 # a i r4
    # total = total + b
   add r2, r2, r5 # öka b med r5
   addi r8, r8, 1 # i = i + 1
   br L1 # goto L1
L2: # return( total )
ret
```

How can I call the subroutine and print something from it to make sure that it is working as expected? This is my first subroutine and I have never called a subroutine before, so please pardon me if I don't understand everything right away.

Comment: @Anon ymous Thank you for the comment. I've updated the question with more infor about environment and assembler. It's 32 bit MIPS with the Altera DE2 development board, the IDE I use is called Nios II which also is the name of the processor that is used. Please ask more questions if you like.

Comment: Never confronted such environment, but if it is producing elf then use [int 0x80](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html).Also to call a routine there must be a `call` instruction or a `jump` instruction.

Comment: @Anon ymous `int 0x80` is for x86 only. OP is using MIPS.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. In my environment the call is simply by statement `call` in the code e.g. to call the subroutine `foo` in MIPS I'd just do `call foo` and then the arguments and transported automatically behind the scenes and the same goes for the return value, it's like all registers are "global variables" on the heap in assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the subroutine from main like this:

```
main:
  ...
  li r4, 123    // load some test data into r4 and r5
  li r5, 1
  jal muladd    // call muladd. Return address is stored in r31
  nop           // branch delay slot
  // muladd returns to this address. 
  // If muladd worked correctly r2 should contain decimal 123+1, or 124
  // print subroutine call goes here
  ...
```

Muladd returns by using `jr r31` (jump to the address contained in register 31). Your non-standard environment may be spelling this as `ret`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case I could use just the statement `call`